# status_stack_buffer_overrun error message - automated chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have a Python Script to enter in a website and create some jobs there. This code has working untill the monday, but now It's not working.
The problem is that automated chrome is with a error message "STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN" and can't access any website. In "normal chrome" is working normally.
I already tried delete the caches and disable unused extensions, but it hasn't been resolved. Could you help me?

Below the simple code that i'm executing

```py
import selenium from selenium import webdriver

nav = webdriver.Chrome()
nav.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Below the images (normal chrome x automated chrome)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiiXJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNa09.png)

I already tried delete the caches and disable unused extensions, but it hasn't been resolved.